# How to Force ASP.NET to Handle User's Request respectively?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to Handle simultaneous user requests respectively in ASP.NET WebApi? I don't want to ignore user request with throttling and I don't want to add user session cause I have User UUID. Due to multi-threading issue I want user request to be added inside a queue and whenever it's previous request finished next one happen.

Edit :
I Have an Android app and using retrofit. It's possible that the client send two request at the same time and IIS will handle it in two different threads. I want user request with special UUID be handled respectively in the pipeline and not at the same time.

Edit :
I want this in ASP.NET https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ab3d320b740b881b173a7f19b6e02a01326ad1dc/68747470733a2f2f7374726f6e676c6f6f702e636f6d2f77702d636f6e74656e742f75706c6f6164732f323031342f30312f746872656164696e675f6a6176612e706e67

Comment: Is your question how to demolish IIS to the point that it processes one request at a time? That does not sound like the way to go. What problem are you trying to solve exactly, and why can't you fix that in application code?

Comment: No I don't want to demolish IIS. Imagine a user with special UserID is sending a reuqest and at the same time has another request in the pipeline. I want it to be handled in order.

Comment: Does the client application expect a response from the server? Or is it fire and forget requests that should be processed successively?

Comment: @Jeb: the question is **why** would you like to handle request in an order, one at a time rather than handle them concurrently. What specific condition forces you into this atypical approach.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov , Client cares about response and react based on response but it imagines it's requests will be handled respectively. for example buying something and getting list of something, the issue is that the server is not stateless. and request affect each other

Comment: Your edit doesn't explain anything. It is still unclear why a user sending **two** requests at the same time would not be allowed to have both requests processed concurrently. Could you elaborate more on your specific business requirement behind your reasoning? Most probably you could solve your issues at the database level or by using a queuing middleware. But a background is needed to recommend a reliable solution.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yeah I need a queuing  middleware to queue all user requests in different queues and response that special user request if it doesn't have another request.

Comment: You cannot achieve that on the server without killing it. Can't you handle this on the client? Ensure that a second request is not sent until the first one completes?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Imagine sending 20 reuqest at the same time. client is multi threaded and checking if the previous request succeeded and sending another request cause the client wait for the time on request going on the wire then server prepare the response and whenever got the result sending again. but If I implement it on server, server will respond in less waiting time and client will get responses in order and with less waiting time.

Comment: What makes you think that it will take less time from the client perspective if you implement the waiting on the server - especially as per your requirements - the server **should not** send the response to the second request until the first one completes? If it was fire and forget requests then this could be implemented using a messaging system on the server, but if your client depends on the responses of the server then you are pretty much out of luck with this design.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov from my perspective it's like this. https://www.mediafire.com/?ddnscfc9j1d8lgw

Comment: The problem with your desired approach is that you will be blocking requests on the server which is very bad as you will quickly run out of worker threads and cripple your server down to a halt.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov , yeah Your're right. I want this https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ab3d320b740b881b173a7f19b6e02a01326ad1dc/68747470733a2f2f7374726f6e676c6f6f702e636f6d2f77702d636f6e74656e742f75706c6f6164732f323031342f30312f746872656164696e675f6a6176612e706e67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to queue up requests from a particular client you could use a named lock:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> lockDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
```

and then inside your server side handler get the user id and ensure that only a single thread can process it at a time:

```
void ProcessRequest()
{
    string userId = GetUserIdFromRequest();
    lock (lockDict.GetOrAdd(userId, s => new object()))
    {
        // do the actual processing here and return response to the client.
    }
}
```

Note however that this approach will only work on a single server environment. If you have server farms you will need to use a distributed named lock implementation instead.

Also note that if you have hundreds of concurrent requests from the same client and those requests take time to execute this will block them up and jeopardize your worker threads on the server eventually impacting other requests.

Personally I would recommend you reviewing your current design and think a little bit more about a stateless architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. I think you should use optimistic concurrency control :

Please see bellow link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application